# netbeans: animate circle drawn using drawline funtion

Tags: java, animation, netbeans, timer

I am trying to draw a circle like this: http://35.197.37.158/Circle/

using drawline function and animate it same as the attached link.

here is what I tried but it draw a line of circle and delete the previous one

This is the class that have my code for drawing a circle and animating it using swin Timer. anyone have better idea to animate the circle ?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CustomPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
         Point [] coordinates;
         GeneralPath circle;
        final int C = 10;
        int j =0;
        int i =j;
        Point p;
        Point p2 ;
        Timer clock = new Timer(100, this);

public CustomPanel()
{
    LinesCoordinates();  
    clock.setInitialDelay(50);
     clock.start();
}


 private void LinesCoordinates()
{        
    int numberOfLines = 360/C;
    coordinates = new Point[numberOfLines];
    double cx = 200.0;
    double cy = 200.0;
    double r = 75.0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int theta = 0; theta < 360; theta+=C)
    {
        int x = (int)(cx + r * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta)));
        int y = (int)(cy + r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta)));
        coordinates[count++] = new Point(x, y);
    }
}


 @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Redraw();
    repaint(); 
    }

public void Redraw(){
    j=j+1;
    p = p2;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setPaint(Color.red);
   // while (j<=coordinates.length){

   while(i<=j){
   j--;
    p2 = coordinates[j % coordinates.length];
    g2.drawLine(p.x, p.y, p2.x , p2.y);

   }}}
```

And this is my Main

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           // public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circle ");
                CustomPanel co = new CustomPanel();
                frame.add(co);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(300, 300);
                frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I was not able to get your solution draw the circle I had to rewrite your code a bit. Here is my solution preserving your JPanel listening to Timer approach. Hopefully this will work for you. I can send the complete [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) project if you want.

```java
package circleanimation;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class CustomPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    final int numberOfPoints = 20;
    Point[] circleCoordinates = new Point[numberOfPoints];
    int nextPointToAnimate = 1;
    Timer clock = new Timer(100, this);

    public CustomPanel() {
        calculateCirclePoints();
        clock.setInitialDelay(50);
        clock.start();
    }

    private void calculateCirclePoints() {
        int angle = 360 / numberOfPoints;
        double cx = 150.0;
        double cy = 150.0;
        double r = 75.0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int totalAngle = 0; totalAngle < 360; totalAngle = totalAngle + angle) {
            int x = (int) (cx + r * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(totalAngle)));
            int y = (int) (cy + r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(totalAngle)));
            circleCoordinates[count++] = new Point(x, y);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        for (int i = 0; i < nextPointToAnimate; i++) {
            Point firstPoint = circleCoordinates[i];
            Point secondPoint;
            if (i == numberOfPoints - 1) {
                secondPoint = circleCoordinates[0];
            } else {
                secondPoint = circleCoordinates[i + 1];
            }
            g.drawLine(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y, secondPoint.x, secondPoint.y);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        nextPointToAnimate++;
        if (nextPointToAnimate == numberOfPoints) {
            clock.stop();
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```